# Theres is a way to be notified in swift if an UIImageView image has been set?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uikit

if UIImageView were my class I would have solved this by doing:

```
class myUIImageView{
  var image : UIImage? {
   didSet {
    if self.image != nil{
      //do my stuff
    }
   }
  }

  //Other fields and functions
}
```

> What I want is to be notified (*Observer Like*)

Comment: try to use Post Notification it will solve your problem

Comment: @MalavSoni can you please elaborate? What is Post Notification and how it should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find the answer... Swift allows to override `var` so there is no real complication here. Just change where you use `UIImageView` to be using `myUIImageView`.

```
class myUIImageView : UIImageView{

 override var image: UIImage?{
    didSet {
        if image != nil{
           //do your stuff (add effects, layers, ...)
        } else {
          //clean your filter or added layer (remove your effects over the view)
        }
    }
 }

}
```

**UPDATE**

> Be advice, if your UIImageView is part of a Collection View you should remove the effect when the collection reuses your view. Otherwise it will remain visible even if no image is being shown.

Comment: You can reset your collection view by overriding prepareForReuse() [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse)

Answer (score 0):

You should treat a view controller's views as private. The only object that should be changing a UIImageView is the UIViewController it belongs to.

Assuming you do that, then the view controller can do whatever you want when it changes the image view's image.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to get to know when the image is set to apply some effect over the view...don't know if you remember..this is a continuation of my previous questions about gradient background over an UIImageView. I'm loading those images now from a server and looks weird a gradient over a white space waiting for the UIImage to load.